# not able to read self signed certificate in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong:
I have created my self-signed certificate and key file using below command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mykey.key  -x509 -days 365 -out mykey.crt
```

It generates the both key and cert file.
However When I tries to load these file in my Nginx block: it gave me the below error:

```
nginx                          | 2021/05/18 10:54:48 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/mykey.cert": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
nginx                          | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/mykey.cert": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
nginx exited with code 1
```

So, I googled it and as per various suggestions from different questions from stackoverflow, I have tried the below options: but none of them are working.

1. added `TRUSTED` between `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` and tries to reload the Nginx it still threw me the same error.
2. I tried to rewrite the whole `BEGIN` and `END` with 5*- and still the same error.

Then in my local system I tried to read :
`openssl x509 -noout -text -in mykey.crt` --> no problem
while trying to read `openssl x509 -noout -text -in mykey.key` --> it threw me below error
`4566036076:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

Strange I created this same key and cert file in the same MacOS with openssl but when I try to read the same key then I'm getting the error message in the same OS.

Comment: The error message uses a different filename to the command you used to create it. One ends with `.crt` and one ends with `.cert`.

Comment: The cert file contains a cert and can be read by `openssl x509` (as long as you specify the correct file) but the privatekey file does not contain a cert, it contains a privatekey, which is not a cert, so to read it you use (newer) `openssl pkey` or (older) `openssl rsa`. Also the 'expecting TRUSTED CERTIFICATE' is misleading; the PEM routine involved can actually read _either_ CERTIFICATE _or_ TRUSTED CERTIFICATE (the latter being different and _not_ what you have) but when neither is found it can only put one name in the error message and uses the second.

Comment: yes,  thanks Richard that was the issue `crt ` and `cert`